# How to configure Spring MVC to prevent "Path-Based Vulnerability"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC (5.0.8.RELEASE) application and a recent security scan indicates that it has "Path-Based Vulnerability". Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/faq", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String faq(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "faq";
}
```

For the above controller, here is the valid url for my FAQ page:

http://example.com/faq

However, based on the security scan and what I tested, the following url works too:

http://example.com/faq.anything

How can I configure Spring MVC to make http://example.com/faq to the only valid URL? (suppose that I don't use @PathVariable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because spring support suffix ".*" default.
/person is also mapped to /person.*
/person.xml or /person.pdf or /person.any is also mapped.
- To completely disable the use of file extensions, you must set both of these:

.useSuffixPatternMatching(false)

.favorPathExtension(false)

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match

Comment: Hi huy, can you give a code example on how to use these methods.

Comment: Please refer to spring document, it already have a clear example.