# Disabling SuffixPatternMatch in grails 3.3.8

Tags: grails, url-pattern

I am using grails 3.3.8 and by default suffix pattern matching is enabled. This means that a handler with /xyz will also be mapped with /xyz.abc or /xyz.abc.test etc.

We can disable the suffix pattern match in spring as described in https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match

Please help me to disable this in grails.

Comment: If you have a mapping like `"/abc(.$someIgnoredSuffix)?"(controller: 'alpha')` that will match `/abc` and `/abc.def`.  Is that what you want?

Comment: No I want /abc.def to be treated as different url. Don't want to match with /abc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457572/how-to-configure-spring-mvc-to-prevent-path-based-vulnerability need to something similar in groovy

Comment: That is what you get by default.  If you have a mapping like `"/abc"(controller: 'demo')`, that will not match a request to `/abc.def`.

Comment: Right now my grails application shows the same page for /login and /login.xxx , Need a way to disable this.

Comment: "Right now my grails application shows the same page for /login and /login.xxx" - What mapping do you have which is matching `/login.xxx`?

Comment: If you have the default url mapping in place which includes the `(.$format)` suffix, and you have a controller named `LoginController`, then I would expect `/login.xxx` to match.  If that isn't what you wan't, then you don't want to have a mapping like that in place.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Thanks for the help. I have removed (.$format) suffix from UrlMapping and it works as I want.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the default url mapping in place which includes the `(.$format)` suffix, and you have a controller named LoginController, then I would expect `/login.xxx` to match. If that isn't what you want, then you don't want to have a mapping like that in place.