# Path based vulnerability in Spring hybris

Tags: spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud, qualys

We have got path based vulnerability issues in Qualys report. I have gone through stackoverflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457572/how-to-configure-spring-mvc-to-prevent-path-based-vulnerability) and configured useDefaultSuffixPattern as false as shown below.

I am still able to load the page with /about.anything even though in controller I have given as @RequestMapping(value = "/about")

Is there any other configuration we need to update to stop this from happening?

```
    <bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <!-- Set whether to register paths using the default suffix pattern as 
        well: i.e. whether "/users" should be registered as "/users.*" and "/users/" 
        too. Default is "true". Turn this convention off if you intend to interpret 
        your @RequestMapping paths strictly. Note that paths which include a ".xxx" 
        suffix or end with "/" already will not be transformed using the default 
        suffix pattern in any case. -->
    <property name="useDefaultSuffixPattern" value="false" />
    <property name="pathMatcher" ref="pathMatcher" />
</bean>
```

We are using hybris 1811 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be happening because of an [inherent bug in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526523/spring-mvc-pathvariable-getting-truncated) where it ignores everything after the dot(.) in the URL.

To resolve this you must create the [path variable pattern for GET call in your controller more rigid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332092/spring-mvc-pathvariable-with-dot-is-getting-truncated).